# XLib Disconnection Callback

Tags: xlib, xrandr

I use XLib and XRand to get some information about the connected displays on an embedded system.

```
class Foo {
private:
    Display *_display{};

public:
    Foo() {
        _display = XOpenDisplay(":0.0");
    }

    void getSomeInfo() const {
        /* Get some info with _display */
    }

    ~Foo() {
        XCloseDisplay(_display);
    }
}
```

The problem is, X server can be shut down (for low power or some other purposes) after the creation of Foo instance and before calling `getSomeInfo()`, which causes immediate death of my application because XLib tries to exit application in case of errors.

Is there any mechanism, like a callback, which would allow me to understand that X Server went down and I should not use the `_display` pointer anymore ?

Comment: Does "use XCB instead of Xlib" count as an answer? If so, I can provide that as an answer. XCB never calls `exit` for you and it actually provides some error status codes.

Comment: @UliSchlachter sorry for almost 2 years delay :) I think that counts as an answer since I could not find any other sane way than using Xcb. Please answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2):

I fear that your only option is to use `XSetIOErrorHandler` and then do something ugly.

From https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/protocol-errors/XSetIOErrorHandler.html:

> The XSetIOErrorHandler() sets the fatal I/O error handler. Xlib calls the program's supplied error handler if any sort of system call error occurs (for example, the connection to the server was lost). This is assumed to be a fatal condition, and the called routine should not return. If the I/O error handler does return, the client process exits.

The "do something ugly" that I would suggest is to use `setjmp` and `longjmp`: Whenever you call any Xlib functions, you `setjmp` before. Your I/O error handling function then `longjmp`s away to get away from the I/O error without your process exiting.

Comment: I have to say that I'm impressed :) but this kind of tricks are not allowed on our codebase.

Comment: Good for you that such hacks are not allowed. Bad for you that then your only option is Xlib, I guess. (You are not allowed to interpose libc's `exit()` to replace it with your own no-op function, right? ;-) )